# Could we have a less obvious review audit user?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, review-audits

I've noticed a good chunk of my edit approval review audits are by the same user (who I will not name ;p), with a .. suspicious amount of rep (999/1024). I realize that review audits are meant to catch roboapprovals, but at this point I'm like "Oh, its *him* again" and know its a review audit.

Could we have more variation in the user who is used for review audits? It kinda defeats the purpose if its kinda obvious from the same username popping up repeatedly whenever a review audit comes up (even if a roboapprover wouldn't notice this).

Comment: Seriously. I was about to superping a user for crap reviews and only thanks to my due diligence I didn't end up doing that.. else would have been real bad

Comment: I also just realised the user's name is a bad pun

Comment: @JourneymanGeek What name?

Comment: I'm intentionally not mentioning it since, its obvious enough that it would allow for review audit evasion if you knew about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *supposed* to be random - an actual user picked from among recently-registered users who've suggested edits.

You've only had two audits, so I'm pretty comfortable saying this is just bad luck - you could just have easily run into the same username while reviewing *actual* edits.

We'll probably try to make this sort of luck a *bit* less likely in the future though.

Comment: Well, I only brought this up when at least two other users mentioned the same person doing these 'edits'. I suppose the convinient amount of rep, and the name suspeciously sounding like Markov Chains was just Apophenia ? ;p

Comment: Yup - so far as I'm aware, Mr Chan is a real person.

Comment: <_< damn, somehow I'm *oddly dissappointed* he is.

Comment: I'd note I've gotten a different user messing up an edit now