# Too sneaky review audits

Tags: support, review-audits

I was reviewing a first post, and it showed a post by `user......`. The answer looked OK, but I clicked the link to the question to see the other answers, and there was the *exact* same post by `LPChip`. So I flagged it (since I thought it was exactly the same as someone else's post) and it told me I failed the audit.

My question is, why would it have a different username on the answer in the review queue than on the "real" post?

Comment: because this. http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6413/could-we-have-a-less-obvious-review-audit-user?rq=1

Comment: @Sathya OK, thanks. Sorry I can't accept the comment. :)