# Did the review process trick me?

Tags: support

I was reviewing First Posts and I got one that looked like a duplicate of another answer. Here's what it showed me after I failed:

https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/492517

However, when I was presented the post to review, the user information was different. It told me it was a random new user (user#####) with some very low reputation. I am unable to get back to the exact screen it showed me so I can't give you exact information. The answer looked pretty good - because it was - so I went to the actual question to review what other answers existed. The question seemed pretty simple so I expected to find another good answer already posted.

Sure enough, I found the *exact* answer already posted. "Huh," I thought, "some relatively new member has copy / pasted another answer. They must not understand why that's bad." In fact, the answer I was looking at didn't even show up so I guessed it had been posted, deleted, and was now being used to test me.

My plan was to leave a comment in the review panel explaining why it was not a helpful answer and then flag it for moderator intervention. However, as soon as I posted my comment in the review panel, it told me that I failed the test.

I have two questions here:

1. Did I get trolled by the review process or is it common practice to change the user information and comments to make it look like a new user's post?
2. Why did I fail as soon as I commented? How is that indicative of me judging it incorrectly? What if my comment was to say it was a fantastic answer and I welcome them to SuperUser? Even if it *is* a bad answer and I'm going to flag it, isn't it better to leave a comment explaining to the new poster so they don't think people are deleting their posts for no reason?

Comment: I apologise for being vaguely involved in this deceit ;)

Comment: Join the club of people who hate the review audit system, including [Happy](http://meta.superuser.com/q/9156/150988), [Sleepy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188780/195817), [Dopey](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188885/195817), [Grumpy](http://meta.superuser.com/q/8616/150988), [Doc](http://meta.superuser.com/q/9248/150988), [Sneezy](http://meta.superuser.com/q/9285/150988), [Bashful](http://meta.superuser.com/q/10955/150988), and many more (see the **Related** questions column).  Part 1 of your question is a duplicate of [Too sneaky review audits](http://meta.superuser.com/q/8094/150988).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is it common practice to change the user information and comments to make it look like a new user's post?

This is by design.

It's a audit - specifically to test if you can recognise a **good** answer.

The answer is manipulated so you are not biased by recognising the name of the user or by his reputation.

I believe you will only see this happening in the First Posts queue.

---

#### Why did I fail as soon as I commented?

That part of your question is addressed here [Clicking “Add comment” fails review audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188885/clicking-add-comment-fails-review-audit)

Comment: I didn't realize the issue was so widespread. Thanks.

Comment: It's not an issue though

Comment: @Ramhound What's not an issue?

Comment: @Ramhound Allow me to rephrase. I did not realize that complaints about some of the finer points of the review audit system were so common.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Toast indicated that an issue was widespread, I just wanted to point out, this behavior is by design.  So it really isn't an issue per say.

Comment: @Ramhound OK. Good point. I will add that to the answer.

Comment: The reason you fail the audit, when it provides you a good question, is because your not suppose to do anything with a good question.  Due to the type of questions we get, we might need to ask a question, but its also a good idea to look at the actual question ( and its answers ) itself you are reviewing.  A good question, technically only should result in two actions, answering it or upvoting it.  You can only do one of those things in the review queue process.

Comment: I think this chicanery also occurs in the Late Answers queue, but I can't recall a specific instance.

Comment: @BenN You could well be right ...